# Convert from String to HTML tag

Tags: javascript

My question is how to convert string in anchor. Instead of a link, it shows html code. I think that problem is in `a.forEach(li))`, but I don't know how to solve this problem. (Yeah yeah is a bad code :D. I am just trying to make a list using only js  )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myArray = 
        ['<a href="https://ceiti.md/">CEITI</a>', 
        ['<a href="#">Inner Value 1</a>', 
        '<a href="#">Inner Value 2</a>', 
        '<a href="#">Inner Value 3</a>',
        '<a href="#">Inner Value 4</a>'], 
        '<a href="#">Value 2</a>',
        '<a href="#">Value 3</a>',
        '<a href="#">Value 4</a>',
        '<a href="#">Value 5</a>',
        '<a href="#">Value 6</a>'];
    function iter(target) {
        var ul = document.createElement('ul'),
            li;
            ul.setAttribute('class','lifin');
        target.appendChild(ul);
            return function (a) {
            if (Array.isArray(a)) {

                                if (!li) {
                                    li = document.createElement('li');
                                    ul.appendChild(li);
                                }
                                a.forEach(iter(li));
                                ul.setAttribute('id','proList');
                                li.setAttribute('id','pList');
                                return;
                            }
                            li = document.createElement('li');
                            li.setAttribute('id','Mon');
                            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));
                            ul.appendChild(li);
                        };
    }
    myArray.forEach(iter(document.getElementById('myList')));

    </script>
```

Comment: The problem is that you are using `createTextNode`. This will literally create a text not, not an element node. Maybe you want `li.innerHTML = a` instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your data model required restructuring. 

What you have is an array of values, but the 2nd item is another array of values. You won't be able to cleanly parse this in any meaningful way.

Instead, make an array of objects, which may or may not contain an array of inner values as an item of the object.

Comment: @FelixKling thank you))

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = 
  ['<a href="https://ceiti.md/">CEITI</a>', 
    [
      '<a href="#">Inner Value 1</a>', 
      '<a href="#">Inner Value 2</a>', 
      '<a href="#">Inner Value 3</a>',
      '<a href="#">Inner Value 4</a>'
    ], 
    '<a href="#">Value 2</a>',
    '<a href="#">Value 3</a>',
    '<a href="#">Value 4</a>',
    '<a href="#">Value 5</a>',
    '<a href="#">Value 6</a>'
  ];
        
  function iter(target) {
      var ul = document.createElement('ul'), li;
      ul.setAttribute('class','lifin');
      target.appendChild(ul);
      return function (a) {
      if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        if (!li) {
          li = document.createElement('li');
          ul.appendChild(li);
        }
        a.forEach(iter(li));
        ul.setAttribute('id','proList');
        li.setAttribute('id','pList');
        return;
      }
      li = document.createElement('li');
      li.setAttribute('id','Mon');
      li.innerHTML = a; // Edited Line
      ul.appendChild(li);
    };
  }
    
myArray.forEach(iter(document.getElementById('myList')));
```

```html
<li id="myList"></li>
```

Just to make answer from @FelixKing clear